# how come an x64 OS can run a code compiled for x86 machine

Tags: 64-bit, x86-64

Basically, what I wonder is how come an x86-64 OS can run a code compiled for x86 machine. I know when first x64 Systems has been introduced, this wasn't a feature of any of them. After that, they somehow managed to do this.

Note that I know that x86 assembly language is a subset of x86-64 assembly language and ISA's is designed in such a way that they can support backward compatibility. But what confuses me here is stack calling conventions. These conventions differ a lot depending on the architecture. For example, in x86, in order to backup frame pointer, proceses pushes where it points to stack(RAM) and pops after it is done. On the other hand, in x86-64, processes doesn't need to update frame pointer at all since all the references is given via stack pointer. And secondly, While in x86 architecture arguments to functions is passed by stack in x86-64, registers are used for that purpose.

Maybe this differences between stack calling conventions of x86-64 and x64 architecture may not affect the way program stack grows as long as different conventions are not used at the same time and this is mostly the case because x32 functions are called by other x32's and same for x64. But, at one point, a function (probably a system function) will call a function whose code is compiled for a x86-64 machine with some arguments, at this point, I am curious about how OS(or some other control unit) handle to get this function work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of the way that the i386/x86-64 architecture is designed is that the [CS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CS_register) and other segment registers refer to entries in the [GDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Descriptor_Table). The GDT entries have a few special bits besides the base and limit that describe the operating mode and privilege level of the current running task.

If the CS register refers to a 32-bit [code segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment), the processor will run in what is essentially i386 compatibility mode. Likewise 64-bit code requires a 64-bit code segment.

So, putting this all together.

When the OS wants to run a 32-bit task, during the task switch into it, it loads a value into CS which refers to a 32-bit code segment. Interrupt handlers also have segment registers associated with them, so when a system call occurs or an interrupt occurs, the handler will switch back to the OS's 64-bit code segment, (allowing the 64-bit OS code to run correctly) and the OS then can do its work and continue scheduling new tasks.

As a follow up with regards to calling convention. Neither i386 or x86-64 **require** the use of frame pointers. The code is free to do as it pleases. In fact, many compilers (gcc, clang, VS) offer the ability to compile 32-bit code without frame pointers. What **is** important is that the calling convention is implemented consistently. If all the code expects arguments to be passed on the stack, that's fine, but the called code better agree with that. Likewise, passing via registers is fine too, just everyone has to agree (at least at the library interface level, internal functions can generally do as they please).

Beyond that, just keep in mind that the difference between the two isn't really an issue because every process gets its own private view of memory. A side consequence though is that 32-bit apps can't load 64-bit dlls, and 64-bit apps can't load 32-bit dlls, because a process either has a 32-bit code segment or a 64-bit code segment. It can't be both.

Comment: Thanks for a thorough and clear answer. Could x86 instructions (utilizing the 32-bit registers - eax, ebx etc) be executed within a 64-bit process?  For example: in the instruction `mov eax, [ecx]`, the value of `ecx` would be treated as a 32-bit address, but as process is of 64-bit, I would thought it could refer to addresses in the 64-bit memory-space only. Theoretically, should this instruction indeed be executable within a 64-bit process?

Comment: @Bliss, yup, all 32 bit registers are fully accessible in 64 bit mode.

Comment: As for the 32 bit registers, you of course need to he careful as the address will be zero extended to 64 bits, that you aren't trying to refer to an address above the 4GB mark with a 32 bit address. Using relative addressing modes largely makes this not a concern though.

Comment: Thanks much. So basically, if I understood you correctly, 32-bit assembly-code could, principally, be executed on a 64-bit CPU, unless it is referring program-data (e.g. variables) which is located in the 64-bit address space (i.e. 64-bit pointers).

Could *small-code model* be applied to a (64-bit) `C#` program (utilizing Visual Studio 2010), as possible in C++?

Answer (score 1):

The processor in put into legacy mode, but that requires everything executing at that time to be 32bit code. This switching is handled by the OS.

> Windows : It uses [**WoW64**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64). WoW64 is responsible for changing the processor mode, it also provides the compatible dll and registry functions.
>
> Linux : Until recently Linux used to (like windows) shift to running the processor in legacy mode when ever it started executing 32bit code, you needed all the 32bit glibc libraries installed, and it would break if it tried to work together with 64bit code. Now there are implementing the [**X32 ABI**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) which should make everything run like smoother and allow 32bit applications to access x64 feature like increased no. of registers. [See this article on the x32 abi](http://lwn.net/Articles/456731/)

PS : I am not very certain on the details of things, but it should give you a start.

Also, this answer combined with Evan Teran's answer probably give a rough picture of everything that is happening.

Comment: WOW64 is more of an API layer part of the solution (it is 32-bit dlls which safely thunk to the 64-bit system calls). It doesn't really address anything on a CPU level. Hense it is short of "Windows on Windows 64". One point of clarification, I wouldn't call it accurate to call it "virtualization", more "abstraction"

Comment: Changed my answer after doing a bit more research. You are right, its would be much better to call it an abstraction layer.